# how to fix greyed out code in inspect element site

Tags: css, web-inspector

I've put an image in the background of a website I'm building, but it's not showing up. I ran inspect mode through Google chrome and the image is greyed out and not being applied.

[image: what inspect mode is displaying]

My css code:

```css
body {
    font-family: Raleway;
    margin: 0;
    background-image: url(background.png);
}
```

I don't have the image listed in the index.html, but it is saved in the images folder. Other images that are listed in the index.html show-up.

I'm creating this site under localhost before publishing it, so I don't have a link to post. However, a link to the image is below.
[what the page looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiOVh.png)

Comment: We can't see the images. Pls recheck your post

Comment: @Pacholoamit, the images are the links at the bottom of the post. I'm not able to embed images to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the image located in the same folder as your index.html? If it is in another folder then you need to reference the file path. [Here's a link regarding file paths](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_filepaths.asp). I encourage you to read on it. You mentioned in it's in a different folder, you have to type that file path on  `background-image: url(FILE PATH HERE)`

Comment: It's not working. The image is in the images folder within the project folder. I've tried putting the entire link in the ()s and it's still not working.

Comment: Can you give me the URL you put in, the directory your image is in, and the index file location. Give me pictures if you want. I'm sure we can figure this out :)

Comment: background-image: url("C:\Bitnami\wordpress-5.5.1-2\apps\wordpress\htdocs\wp-content\themes\sophisticentric-beauty\images\background.png")   the CSS. Should I be putting it in the index.html instead? [link]https://www.dropbox.com/s/uckipnz5f3atcsz/FINAL.jpg?dl=0 what I'm recreating

Comment: If your index.html is located in "sophisticentric-beauty" then try `background-image: url("./images/background.png")`

Comment: That did it! I wonder why it didn't work earlier. I went through the list in the link you originally sent. I must have been missing a quotation mark or something.

Comment: Hahahah see, i told ya. A check mark on my answer would help a lot. So others would see the solution :)

Comment: You have to understand "relative path" when you import something (in this case the image) If you are importing an image to your index file, start from the index file then work your way to the image you are referencing to. Glad to help :)